Duplicating rows and change two columns, based on a values in the row. In Excel
I'm trying to take a stock listing and generate duplicate rows for each of the SKUs - our postal software needs each seperate SKU on its own line.
I'm an utter noob at VBA, can anyone give me a hand?
Here's the basic logic:
1. Look at columns B-F. Count how many have a value (are not empty). 
- Set variable numofrows to that count.
- Set variables Bvalue, Cvalue, Dvalue, Evalue and Fvalue

2. Whilst numofrows is more than 1, do the following:

- Check if Bvalue is more than zero. 
- If it is, change column F to say "SKU1", and column G to be the same value as Bvalue. 
- Set Bvalue to empty. Set numofrows to be current value -1. Restart loop.

Repeat above for C through F.

Example of input data



Name
SKU1
SKU2
SKU3
SKU4
SKU5
Weight




Andrew
1

1


0.6


Bob

3



0.4


Carwen
1
1
1
1
1
1.2


Dave



2
1
0.7


Elizabeth


1


0.3



Example of output data



Name
SKU1
SKU2
SKU3
SKU4
SKU5
Weight
SKU
SKU quantity




Andrew
1

1


0.6
SKU1
1


Andrew
1

1


0.6
SKU3
1


Bob

3



0.4
SKU2
3


Carwen
1
1
1
1
1
1.2
SKU1
1


Carwen
1
1
1
1
1
1.2
SKU2
1


Carwen
1
1
1
1
1
1.2
SKU3
1


Carwen
1
1
1
1
1
1.2
SKU4
1


Carwen
1
1
1
1
1
1.2
SKU5
1


Dave



2
1
0.7
SKU4
2


Dave



2
1
0.7
SKU5
1


Elizabeth


1


0.3
SKU3
1



My actual column headers:
Here's the actual headers off my spreadsheet:



Backer Num
Name
Email
Full Name
Address1
Address2
City
State/Province/Region
Zip Code
Country/Region
Country/Region Code
Phone Number
Total Order Weight(kg)
DUN1
Book5
SKUexample
MoreBookSKU
Other
SKUsheets
Size




188
Example
email@whatever.com
Biggles
123 Lala land

Walestown
WL
12345
United States
US
41414141414
0.25
1
2
1
4
5
1
Large Letter





Load data into an array and convert it in memory.

Microsoft documentation:

Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)


IsNumeric function


Range.Resize property (Excel)

Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Dim arrRes, iR As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1") ' modify as needed
    Set rngData = oSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    Dim RowCnt As Long, ColCnt As Long
    RowCnt = UBound(arrData)
    ColCnt = UBound(arrData, 2)
    ReDim arrRes(1 To RowCnt * (ColCnt - 2), 1 To ColCnt + 2)
        For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
            arrRes(1, j) = arrData(1, j)
        Next j
    arrRes(1, j) = "SKU"
    arrRes(1, j + 1) = "SKU Quantity"
    iR = 1
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        For k = LBound(arrData, 2) + 1 To UBound(arrData, 2) - 1
            If Val(arrData(i, k)) > 0 And Len(arrData(i, k)) > 0 And IsNumeric(arrData(i, k)) Then
                iR = iR + 1
                For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
                    arrRes(iR, j) = arrData(i, j)
                Next
                arrRes(iR, j) = arrData(1, k)
                arrRes(iR, j + 1) = arrData(i, k)
            End If
        Next k
    Next i
    Sheets.Add
    Range("A1").Resize(iR, UBound(arrRes, 2)).Value = arrRes
End Sub



For k = LBound(arrData, 2) + 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)-1 to skip the last col in the source data. You could add code lines to validate the col name in the header row if needed.

Thanks for this! Absolutely works on this simplified spreadsheet.
What is the marker that signifies which columns are the SKU ones? My actual spreadsheet is much more complicated, and I can't get this script to pick up the actual SKU columns rather than duplicating bits of the address fields, etc.
Would you mind commenting where the change should be?

Okay I'll have a fiddle with that. I've added my actual column titles in the above date. It sound like I need to work out how many columns there are total and just + the beginning and minus the end.
Thanks so much for this, saved me hours

What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?
The sample data should follow the same pattern as your actual data; otherwise, you will need to revise the code.

What is the marker that signifies which columns are the SKU ones?   - The core logic needs to be established first. It might be Total Order Weight.

It's great I got it sorted thanks, using:
For k = LBound(arrData, 2) + 14 To UBound(arrData, 2) - 1
